# postgres r2dbc gives ssl error but connects using jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, ssl, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

**r2dbc config:**

> ```
> spring:
>   profiles: default   r2dbc:
>   url: r2dbc:postgresql://testserver.dev.net:1234/test?ssl=true&sslmode=require
>   username: test
>   password: test
>   connection_timeout: 20000
> ```

**jpa config:**

> ```
> spring:
> profiles: default
>   datasource:
>     url: jdbc:postgresql://testserver.dev.net:1234/test?ssl=true&sslmode=require
>     username: test
>     password: test
>     hikari:
>         connectionTimeout: 20000
>         maximumPoolSize: 5
> ```

The jpa connection works fine and returns the results, r2dbc fails to connect to the server sighting unable to find valid certificate

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

with r2dbc and ssl off it says pg_hba.conf does not have entry for the host. Why does it only asks for certificate with r2dbc config.

dependencies with r2dbc:

> ```
> <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
>     </dependency> <dependency>
>         <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
>         <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
>         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
> ```

with jpa I am using spring web starter and jpa starter, both are spring version 2.4.1.
I am stuck with this, cant find a reason for this error. Any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the "sslmode" param in r2dbc url to "sslMode". R2dbc seems to default the sslmode as "verify-full" if you dont pass sslMode as paramter and that is why you see exceptions that it is unable to find the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

If you have all the certificates, here is the configuration you can use, It worked for me. Make sure the certificates are in resources folder & they should be only in pem format.

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:pool:postgresql://<DB_HOST>:<DB_PORT>/<DB_NAME>
    username: <DB_USER>
    password: <DB_PASSWORD>
    properties:
      ssl: true
      sslMode: VERIFY_CA
      sslRootCert: root.pem
      sslCert: server.pem
      sslKey: key.pem
```

Comment: Where do you get all the various pem files?